snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be
I tried to run multipass version and got the error below:
snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
Please make sure that the snapd.apparmor service is enabled and started.

This was after I purged snap from my system and reinstalled it.
apparmor is running:
sudo systemctl status apparmor                                           10:48:49
● apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2024-09-29 08:40:08 WAT; 2h 11min ago
       Docs: man:apparmor(7)
             https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/home/
   Main PID: 1009 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 290ms

Sep 29 08:40:08 davidshare systemd[1]: Starting apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles...
Sep 29 08:40:08 davidshare apparmor.systemd[1009]: Restarting AppArmor
Sep 29 08:40:08 davidshare apparmor.systemd[1009]: Reloading AppArmor profiles
Sep 29 08:40:08 davidshare apparmor.systemd[1156]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disabl>
Sep 29 08:40:08 davidshare systemd[1]: Finished apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles.

Things I have tried:
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*
$ sudo systemctl enable --now apparmor.service
$ sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.apparmor.service

$ sudo service start snapd
$ sudo systemctl enable snapd.service
$ sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.service

sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine*

aa-status for snap-confine:
sudo aa-status                                                           10:45:45
apparmor module is loaded.
188 profiles are loaded.
91 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /media/davidshare/Tersu/TersuCorp/tersu tech/learning DevOps/multipass
   /snap/core/17200/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/17200/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/snapd/21759/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/21759/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/bin/evince
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
   /usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince//snap_browsers
   /usr/bin/freshclam
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/bin/snap//passt
   /usr/bin/snap//sanitized_helper
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/sbin/clamd
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
   /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party
   /usr/sbin/sssd
   /{,usr/}sbin/dhclient
   1password
   avahi-daemon

snap version:
snap version                                                                                                                                                             11:03:26
snap    2.63.1+24.04
snapd   2.63.1+24.04
series  16
ubuntu  24.04
kernel  6.8.0-45-generic


Had the same problem; tried same fixes as you without luck.
The fix posted hours ago in Snaps won't open
worked for me and persisted after a reboot.
